# Enable shortcodes in a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I develop a new theme for wordpress 3.3.1 from scratch and shortcodes are not working on it.
As I searched until now it is a matter of filtering the content containing the shortcode, filter code added in a theme specific location(shorcodes are working with another theme).
So, my question is : What is the code for a general shortcode theme enable ?

Comment: Where are you calling the shortcodes?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To execute a single shortcode, run it with

```
echo do_shortcode('[your_short_code]');
```

If the shortcode(s) are in the post content, make sure you're displaying it with

```
<?php the_content();?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$post_content);?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$wp_query->post->post_content);?>
```

The important thing is: if you aren't using the function "the_content()" you need this line `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$wp_query->post->post_content);?>` where in the second argument you have to put the variable of the post content you want to show.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me.   $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ).  I still get [code language=”css”]
test
[/code]

Comment: You rock.  Saved my butt!

Answer (score 0):

I had to save the theme's content to a variable and then use the second example.. Worked like a charm.

```
$mycontent = ot_get_option('rightcontent');                     
echo apply_filters('the_content',$mycontent);
```