# Wordpress plugin shortscodes in other plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a plugin that creates custom wordpress pages, however I ran into a problem when trying to get shortcodes from other plugins to integrate into my plugin, well more like I couldn't find any info on it.

For example if someone uses my custom page builder and adds a short code [gallery] that is associated with an enabled plugin, I want the shortcode to do it's thing.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: I think this previous topic would help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820190/enable-shortcodes-in-a-wordpress-theme

Answer (score 0):

Try wordpress

http://wordpress.org/plugins/synved-shortcodes/

while this plugin let's you integrate shortcodes on every wordpress page , I suppose that you issue is with wordpress functions.php file where you can have a look at , with this plugin installed !

Comment: There is a high probability that this answer might attract downvotes because of being a _link-only-answer_. You should add some additional info (explanation, usage, issues, etc). And welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you for giving me a helping hand !

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a shortcode exist before printing it with the function `shortcode_exists()` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_exists)

Example:

```
<?php
if ( shortcode_exists( 'gallery' ) ) {
    // The [gallery] short code exists.
}
?>
```

Then, if it exist and you want to print that shortcode with PHP code you should use `do_shortcode()` function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

Example:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use in WordPress's in-built

> the_content

hook to print your custom page content.

WordPress by default process all shortcodes before outputting any stuff from this hook.

More info can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content